# How do I boot Win10 from the Grub Menu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

- partitioned my ssd and installed windows 10. It worked fine.
- then installed ubuntu 20.04
- grub wasn't showing on boot but after some tinkering with the boot order in UEFI it showed up and       ubuntu worked just fine too

One problem, Windows isn't in the grub menu when i boot now. Is there a way to add it to the grub menu?

Both operating systems work and are installed on the same ssd in their own partitions

I've read through several articles and I've tried os-prober and then update-grub. Windows doesn't show up. Any help would be great

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. That also means Windows fast start up/ hibernation must be off. And both must be installed in same boot mode, or now almost all systems are UEFI, so both should be in UEFI boot mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Fast start is just not an option in the menu it is usually found in. Same with hibernation but I ran powercfg.exe /hibernate off as admin just in case.

So I can go between os's but through uefi. Just not showing on the grub menu

Comment: Did you then rerun `sudo update-grub`? If not lets see your configuration: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I reran both sudo os-prober and sudo update-grub after, they don't detect windows. Just for more info: I can run win10 if I set Windows Boot Manager first and Ubuntu if I set it first in UEFI but neither seems to see each other. Here's the pastebin link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TyXyzthm8z/

Comment: See line 85. You have mixed UEFI Windows & BIOS Ubuntu. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible, or once you start to boot you cannot change boot mode. And then grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode. Reboot and boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode and add Boot-Repair again. Then use advanced options to totally reinstall grub. How you boot installer or repair ISO is then how it installs or repairs. You just need to always boot in UEFI mode.It looks like your BIOS boot may now reinstall the UEFI grub.

Comment: I did exactly that, re-install ububtu on uefi mode and it works just fine. Thank you very much :)